# Lag selection when completing a lbqtest in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to complete a Q test to test for residual correlation in matlab.

I first run a regression model and take the residuals,

Then I use the following code

```
[~,pvalue,stat,~]=lbqtest(resid, 'Lags', [1:12])
```

I am wondering if this code can tell me the best lag to select according to the AIC/BIC or any of the other information criteria.

Specifically is the value in stat the BIC and should I choose the lowest one?

Comment: What do you mean by best lag to select?? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to select the lag based on the information criteria, so which lag should I use, 12, 5, 3 etc?

Comment: let me rephrase my question. What is your intention once you have selected what you are defining as an appropriate lag? Also, lbqtest does not return any information criterion values, so i am not seeing a connection. AIC/BIC etc.. are typically used as a measure of model parsimony for estimating an appropriate number of parameters.